# Seeking help with my python loop - a basic MAX7219 8 Digit Seven Segment Display Module driver for a Pico W

Tags: python, serial

I am trying to send serial data to a MAX7219 8 Digit Seven Segment Display Module from a Pico W. I can blank the display or make every last LED light up but nothing else. I cannot currently see what I have done wrong.

### Details

I went the Python route and downloaded Thonny. Then I looked up a datasheet which I found [here](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MAX7219.pdf).

What I am trying to do is create a loop that will take an array of bits (not necessarily efficiently) that will display digits with whatever LEDs I choose.

### Connections

I put power on VBus and ground on ground. Yes, that is enough power, it seems.
GP14 to DIN (Data in)
GP15 to CS/Load
GP18 to CLK

### The code

This is my not especially well-written python. It is the result of fiddling about until I figured things out.

I've assumed a baud rate that should fit within 10Mhz and divided 1 second by it. I use that for a sleep call before stepping the clock forwards.

If I send a reset command 16 bits of all zeros, that works like a dream - display blanks out.

Anything else either does nothing or lights up all the LEDs.

The expected outcome is that the array `my_rnd_bits` should give me an 8 on segment 0 (possibly with a decimal point). I have yet to activate the display in any meaningful way. The actual outcome is everything on or nothing.

**UPDATE**: I have reordered my code a little bit. I have listed (almost) all the commands and registers and such so my bad typing does not cause bugs. This has not got me any further.

```
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep

junk = [0,0,0,0]

register = dict()
register['no-op']=junk+[0,0,0,0]
register['digit0']=junk+[0,0,0,1]
register['digit1']=junk+[0,0,1,0]
register['digit2']=junk+[0,0,1,1]
register['digit3']=junk+[0,1,0,0]
register['digit4']=junk+[0,1,0,1]
register['digit5']=junk+[0,1,1,0]
register['digit6']=junk+[0,1,1,1]
register['digit7']=junk+[1,0,0,0]
register['decode mode']=junk+[1,0,0,1]
register['intensity']=junk+[1,0,1,0]
register['scan limit']=junk+[1,0,1,1]
register['shutdown']=junk+[1,1,0,0]
register['test']=junk+[1,1,1,1]

command = dict()
command['shutdown'] = register['shutdown'] + junk + [0,0,0,0] # shutdown mode
command['normal'] = register['shutdown'] + junk + [0,0,0,1]   # Normal Opperation
command['reset'] = [0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0]
# Mode B for digits
command['none'] = register['decode mode'] + [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]   # Normal Opperation
# others in here if I can be bothered later
command['all'] = register['decode mode'] + [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]   # Normal Opperation

codeBFont = dict()
codeBFont['0'] = junk+[0,0,0,0]
codeBFont['1'] = junk+[0,0,0,1]
codeBFont['2'] = junk+[0,0,1,0]
codeBFont['3'] = junk+[0,0,1,1]
codeBFont['4'] = junk+[0,1,0,0]
codeBFont['5'] = junk+[0,1,0,1]
codeBFont['6'] = junk+[0,1,1,0]
codeBFont['7'] = junk+[0,1,1,1]
codeBFont['8'] = junk+[1,0,0,0]
codeBFont['9'] = junk+[1,0,0,1]
codeBFont['-'] = junk+[1,0,1,0]
codeBFont['E'] = junk+[1,0,1,1]
codeBFont['H'] = junk+[1,1,0,0]
codeBFont['L'] = junk+[1,1,0,1]
codeBFont['P'] = junk+[1,1,1,0]
codeBFont[' '] = junk+[1,1,1,1]
codeBFont['blank'] = codeBFont[' ']

intensity = dict()
intensity[0] = junk+[0,0,0,0]
intensity[1] = junk+[0,0,0,1]
intensity[2] = junk+[0,0,1,0]
intensity[3] = junk+[0,0,1,1]
intensity[4] = junk+[0,1,0,0]
intensity[5] = junk+[0,1,0,1]
intensity[6] = junk+[0,1,1,0]
intensity[7] = junk+[0,1,1,1]
intensity[8] = junk+[1,0,0,0]
intensity[9] = junk+[1,0,0,1]
intensity[10] = junk+[1,0,1,0]
intensity[11] = junk+[1,0,1,1]
intensity[12] = junk+[1,1,0,0]
intensity[13] = junk+[1,1,0,1]
intensity[14] = junk+[1,1,1,0]
intensity[15] = junk+[1,1,1,1]

scanlimit = dict()
scanlimit[0] = junk+[0,0,0,0] # 0 only
scanlimit[1] = junk+[0,0,0,1] # 0 - 1
scanlimit[2] = junk+[0,0,1,0] # 0 - 2
scanlimit[3] = junk+[0,0,1,1] # 0 - 3
scanlimit[4] = junk+[0,1,0,0] # 0 - 4
scanlimit[5] = junk+[0,1,0,1] # 0 - 5
scanlimit[6] = junk+[0,1,1,0] # 0 - 6
scanlimit[7] = junk+[0,1,1,1] # 0 - 7

testmode = dict()
testmode['normal'] = junk+[0,0,0,0]
testmode['display'] = junk+[0,0,0,1]
def Seg7Send(bits):
    #baudr = (1/9600)*1 #multiplier is to slow the clk rate
    baudr = 5*(10^-8)
    p_cs = Pin(15,Pin.OUT) #CS/LOAD
    p_din = Pin(14,Pin.OUT) #DIN
    p_clk = Pin(18,Pin.OUT) #CLK
    hilo = 0
    counter = 0
    for bit in bits:
        counter += 1
        hilo = 1-hilo
        p_clk.value(hilo) #clock pulse
        p_din.value(bit) # send bit
        #print(f"bit: {bit}"); #debug
        if(counter>15):
            #print(f"clk: {hilo}"); #debug
            p_cs.value(1) # load
            counter = 0
        sleep(baudr) #Regulate clock
    p_cs.value(0) # reset
    p_din.value(0) # reset


mycommand = command['reset']+command['normal'] # not sure if this is necessary
mycommand = mycommand + register['scan limit']+scanlimit[7] # scan limit - show all digits
mycommand = mycommand + command['all']+register['digit0'] # decode mode B all digits
mycommand = mycommand + codeBFont['H']

print(f"Command: {command}")
Seg7Send(mycommand)
```

This has left me wondering if there is a handshake or prefix I need to send; if I have just missed a step; or if I have totally misunderstood something.

As might be obvious from all the commented-out stuff, I have experimented with going faster and slower. I have tried a bunch of stuff and then (in desperation) experimented with random data (no a great move).

Have I misunderstood how the clock should work? Missed a protocol header? Been an idiot (always a possibility), or just got something wrong?

Comment: You never send bit0.

Comment: @KennethAndersen is that I don't send it or I do but shouldn't?

Comment: You should. First you set counter to 0, but as soon as you enter the `for bit in bits` , counter is incremented.

Comment: That's right - so at the 16th (counter>15) we can also set the CS/LOAD pin high. Is that a mistake?

Comment: I think I have cracked it. I send data only on CLK-high. I am now getting some sensible output. Not perfect but closer than I was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The fault was not with the loop (as such) but with my reading of the chip details. The breakthrough was to do the following:

1. Set CS-high on the same clock pulse as the 16th bit. For my chip, that
   might have been optional.
2. Send data only on CLK-high and nothing on CLK-low

### Special thanks

Kenneth Andersen's comment about checking how many bits I was sending forced me to look closer at when CS/LOAD should be set which made me look at the Timing Diagram.

### code

```
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep
from picozero import pico_led

junk = [0,0,0,0]

register = dict()
register['no-op']=junk+[0,0,0,0]
register['digit0']=junk+[0,0,0,1]
register['digit1']=junk+[0,0,1,0]
register['digit2']=junk+[0,0,1,1]
register['digit3']=junk+[0,1,0,0]
register['digit4']=junk+[0,1,0,1]
register['digit5']=junk+[0,1,1,0]
register['digit6']=junk+[0,1,1,1]
register['digit7']=junk+[1,0,0,0]
register['decode mode']=junk+[1,0,0,1]
register['intensity']=junk+[1,0,1,0]
register['scan limit']=junk+[1,0,1,1]
register['shutdown']=junk+[1,1,0,0]
register['test']=junk+[1,1,1,1]

command = dict()
command['shutdown'] = register['shutdown'] + junk + [0,0,0,0] # shutdown mode
command['normal'] = register['shutdown'] + junk + [0,0,0,1]   # Normal Opperation
command['reset'] = [0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0]
# Mode B for digits
command['none'] = register['decode mode'] + [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]   
# others in here if I can be bothered later
command['all'] = register['decode mode'] + [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]   

codeBFont = dict()
codeBFont['0'] = junk+[0,0,0,0]
codeBFont['1'] = junk+[0,0,0,1]
codeBFont['2'] = junk+[0,0,1,0]
codeBFont['3'] = junk+[0,0,1,1]
codeBFont['4'] = junk+[0,1,0,0]
codeBFont['5'] = junk+[0,1,0,1]
codeBFont['6'] = junk+[0,1,1,0]
codeBFont['7'] = junk+[0,1,1,1]
codeBFont['8'] = junk+[1,0,0,0]
codeBFont['9'] = junk+[1,0,0,1]
codeBFont['-'] = junk+[1,0,1,0]
codeBFont['E'] = junk+[1,0,1,1]
codeBFont['H'] = junk+[1,1,0,0]
codeBFont['L'] = junk+[1,1,0,1]
codeBFont['P'] = junk+[1,1,1,0]
codeBFont[' '] = junk+[1,1,1,1]
codeBFont['blank'] = codeBFont[' ']

intensity = dict()
intensity[0] = junk+[0,0,0,0]
intensity[1] = junk+[0,0,0,1]
intensity[2] = junk+[0,0,1,0]
intensity[3] = junk+[0,0,1,1]
intensity[4] = junk+[0,1,0,0]
intensity[5] = junk+[0,1,0,1]
intensity[6] = junk+[0,1,1,0]
intensity[7] = junk+[0,1,1,1]
intensity[8] = junk+[1,0,0,0]
intensity[9] = junk+[1,0,0,1]
intensity[10] = junk+[1,0,1,0]
intensity[11] = junk+[1,0,1,1]
intensity[12] = junk+[1,1,0,0]
intensity[13] = junk+[1,1,0,1]
intensity[14] = junk+[1,1,1,0]
intensity[15] = junk+[1,1,1,1]

scanlimit = dict()
scanlimit[0] = junk+[0,0,0,0] # 0 only
scanlimit[1] = junk+[0,0,0,1] # 0 - 1
scanlimit[2] = junk+[0,0,1,0] # 0 - 2
scanlimit[3] = junk+[0,0,1,1] # 0 - 3
scanlimit[4] = junk+[0,1,0,0] # 0 - 4
scanlimit[5] = junk+[0,1,0,1] # 0 - 5
scanlimit[6] = junk+[0,1,1,0] # 0 - 6
scanlimit[7] = junk+[0,1,1,1] # 0 - 7

testmode = dict()
testmode['normal'] = junk+[0,0,0,0]
testmode['display'] = junk+[0,0,0,1]
def Seg7Send(bits):
    #baudr = (1/9600)*1 #multiplier is to slow the clk rate
    baudr = 5*(10^-8)
    p_cs = Pin(15,Pin.OUT) #CS/LOAD
    p_din = Pin(14,Pin.OUT) #DIN
    p_clk = Pin(18,Pin.OUT) #CLK
    p_clk.value(0)
    sleep(baudr)
    counter = 0
    for bit in bits:
        counter += 1
        p_clk.value(0) #clock low
        pico_led.off()
        p_cs.value(0) # CS low
        sleep(baudr) #Regulate clock
        p_din.value(bit) # send bit
        p_clk.value(1) #clock pulse
        pico_led.on()
        if(counter>15): # CS high on 16th rising edge
            p_cs.value(1) # load
            counter = 0
        sleep(baudr) #Regulate clock
    p_cs.value(0) # reset
    p_din.value(0) # reset





mycommand = []
mycommand = command['shutdown'] 
mycommand = mycommand + register['scan limit']+scanlimit[7] # scan limit - show all digits
mycommand = mycommand + command['all'] # decode mode B all digits
mycommand = mycommand + register['digit0'] + codeBFont['H']
mycommand = mycommand + register['digit1'] + codeBFont['0']
mycommand = mycommand + register['digit2'] + codeBFont['2']
mycommand = mycommand + register['digit3'] + codeBFont['4']
mycommand = mycommand + register['digit4'] + codeBFont['6']
mycommand = mycommand + register['digit5'] + codeBFont['8']
mycommand = mycommand + register['digit6'] + codeBFont['1']
mycommand = mycommand + register['digit7'] + codeBFont['0']
mycommand = mycommand + command['normal'] + register['no-op']


#print(f"Command: {mycommand}")
Seg7Send(mycommand)
```

### TL;DR:

Make sure to send data on but not between clock signals.

### Bonus tip

I had some trouble with digit-0 resetting to zero after the display loop was done. This was due to junk code from my earlier testing. Always clean up your debug and testing code.

Comment: Please accept your own answer. This closes the question so that it doesn't keep reappearing periodically.